# Two different partial view using asp.net core 2.2 ,java script model ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-ajax

How to implement this using Ajax? i got data in JSON format but not appear on pop up model. i have two partcial view and one main controller 
IT HAS NOT SHOW MODEL ONLY POP UP BLACK SCREEN 
Thanks in advance

**model** :

```
public class OnboardModel
{
    //public string Userid { get; set; }

    public string NodeIdx { get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**controller:  Dashboard/Getinfo**

```
 public IActionResult Getxyzinfo(string nodeid = "7", string userid = "1" ,   string languageid = "1")
        {
            var RecentInfo = Buildxyzinfo(nodeidx, useridx, languageidx);

            return Json(new { success = true, recentinfoData = RecentInfo });
        }
```

**html _index.cshtml**  one partial view

How to create new partial with call using ajax

how to call partial view

**JavaScript :**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                $('#showGoogle').click(function () {
                                    var url = $('#myModal').data('url');

                                    $.get(url, function (data) {
                                        $('#googleContainer').html(data);

                                        $('#myModal').modal('show');

                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
```

_index.cshtml partcial view

```
                            <div id='googleContainer'>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <a href="#" id="showGoogle">Invitation Business</a>
                    </div>
```

other _getinfo.cshtml  partial view

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="googleContainer" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        &times;
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                        Serial Numbers
                    @*</h4>*@
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <span id="test"></span>


    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Googlename, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
 <span class"control-label col-md-3">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.xyzitem.Googlename)</span>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                        Close
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to call partial view"? I see you call `$('#partial').load(route);`  Does that not work?

Comment: yes,that not works for me..

Comment: So which part not work? Does the server return a response?

Comment: no,i think problem with Nodeidx ...

Comment: If the server doesn't `respond`, I believe you should check whether the server is running. At least, you should tell us the status code returned by server.

Comment: yes i got 200  ..

Comment: Could you please show us the complete code ? I see you update the code, but I'm confused now. Where's the partial action method and view ?  The `Getxyzinfo` action method returns JSON, but your ajax method replaces the div by `$('#googleContainer').html(data);`

Comment: yes i solved it i used this one $("#googlecontanier").html(response.recentInfoData);...Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "#showmodal", function (nodeIdx) {

                $.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    url: '@Url.Action("Getxyzinfo", "Dashboard")',
                    data: { nodeIdx: nodeIdx },
                    type: 'GET',
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#googlecontanier").html(response.recentInfoData);

                        $("#myModal").modal("show");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: If you solve this problem, mark it as the answer please :)